# Using express as middleware in apollo server leads to JSON parse error

Tags: node.js, react-native, express, graphql, apollo-server

I'm creating an application where I'm using graphql and react native alongside apollo. When my server code is not using express, I'm able to successfully query from the server using 
`import { useQuery } from '@apollo/react-hooks';`
However, I require express to be able to add a middleware and authenticate users. This throws a: **Error! Network error: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<'**

Works with this code below (without express)

```
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require('apollo-server');

const typeDefs = gql`
  type Book {
    title: String
    author: String
  }

  type Query {
    books: [Book]
  }
`;

const books = [
  {
    title: 'Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets',
    author: 'J.K. Rowling',
  },
  {
    title: 'Jurassic Park',
    author: 'Michael Crichton',
  },
];

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    books: () => books,
  },
};

const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers });

server.listen({ port:4000 }, () => {
  console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:4000${server.graphqlPath}`);
});
```

-

Whereas this code below throws an error

```
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require('apollo-server-express')
const express = require('express');

const typeDefs = gql`
  type Book {
    title: String
    author: String
  }

  type Query {
    books: [Book]
  }
`;

const books = [
  {
    title: 'Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets',
    author: 'J.K. Rowling',
  },
  {
    title: 'Jurassic Park',
    author: 'Michael Crichton',
  },
];

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    books: () => books,
  },
};

const app = express();

const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers });
server.applyMiddleware({ app, path: '/graphql' });

app.listen({ port:4000 }, () => {
  console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:4000${server.graphqlPath}`);
});
```

If this is a parse issue, how do I correctly parse the data? I've tried

```
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.raw())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded())
app.use(bodyParser.text())
```

however this doesn't seem to help :/

Any ideas?

Comment: That's a client-side error that says your response can't be parsed because it's not JSON. Most likely, you're pointing your client at the wrong url. Check the actual response from the server in your browser's dev tools to see what's being sent. And make sure you've removed all that bodyParser middleware -- it's not necessary and can cause you other issues.

Comment: @xadm What's wrong with that?

Comment: @DanielRearden Thank you! Without the middleware, it was automatically redirecting to localhost:graphql, but with the middleware it wasn't redirecting!